# If I add <uses-feature> for android.hardware.camera2.full should I remove android.hardware.camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions, android-camera2, uses-feature

I had

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Then I added the following for the new library:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" android:required="false"/>
```

Do I need to delete the old `android.hardware.camera`  tags  or do I still need to place them to avoid PlayStore from filtering out my app?

The app min target is 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have researched, I must maintain old features which are the ones included in the official Docs:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

The `android.hardware.camera2.full` feature **doesn't exist**. As features are not tightly related to class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

By [official supported devices docs](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/versioning) if your app targets > 21 you can safely remove those flags.